# Using TWAIN in .NET - Looking for resources

Tags: .net, scanning, twain

I'm trying to write some sort of code in .NET to acquire images from network scanner. I have tried WIA and can't even get to see the network scanner, so I am looking at TWAIN now.

Where the problem comes in is that I am having great trouble finding any current information on how to go about doing this.

The main article that keeps coming up is [this 2002 codeproject tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1376/NET-TWAIN-image-scanner). This works, but I understand as good as nothing about what the code is doing, so I'm rather wary about using this.

There is also the 2009 [twaindotnet](https://code.google.com/p/twaindotnet/) project on codeplex whichI actually think I have a chance of understanding so looks much more promising.

I was wondering if there any other useful resources out there about using TWAIN in .Net, or any other open source projects, explanations, tutorials or somesuch that will make it easier to understand how to work with TWAIN? Or the two sources I found really all there is?

Comment: What scanner and are you sure the scanner supports twain?

Comment: Yes, because I can scan with it (and several others) using the twain sample programs.

Comment: About WIA, have you checked that for a start: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8966/using-c-wia-version-2-0-on-vista-to-scan

Comment: @SimonMourier No, I didn't see that, but I already did use WIA and I can't see the my network scanner on there. The scanner is also not visible among my devices, so I assume that it is just not WIA compatible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These resources might be helpful for you:

[TWAIN Specification and TWAIN.h file](http://www.twain.org/scannerdriverdevelopers/specification-and-tools.html)

[TWAIN sample Data Source and Application](http://sourceforge.net/projects/twain-samples/)

Comment: Thanks. I found those, but I'm not familiar with C++ so couldn't make much sense of the info in there.

Comment: Check out the post here on C++->.NET: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637571/creating-simple-c-net-wrapper-step-by-step

You might also consider using a commercial .NET TWAIN SDK. It would be easier and save you time to learn TWAIN.

Comment: Thanks for the link, that is very helpful! I wish I could use third party tools (not just for this), but my company does not spend money on that sort of thing (nor on anything else it seems), so not an option... Picking twaindotnet apart has already got me quite a long way though :)

Comment: +1 for being extra helpful!