# Twain or WIA? A bit lost between this two interface

Tags: c#, .net, api, wia, twain

I need to write a c# assembly (DLL) in order to scan documents.
I don't know if I need to use TWAIN or WIA.

Anyone could help me please ?

- What are the différences?
- What are your advices ?
- Is there a c# Library ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally, if your application is to interact with scanners, TWAIN is recommended. While for cameras, WIA offers better support.

So for document scanning solution, I would recommend TWAIN.

TWAIN.H file is a C/C++ header file. If you want to code it to .NET yourself, you can refer to this post to get some resources:
[Using TWAIN in .NET - Looking for resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16513786/using-twain-in-net-looking-for-resources)

Or you can use a commercial .NET TWAIN component.

Comment: What commercial .NET TWAIN component do you recommend?

Comment: I recommend you try Dynamic .NET TWAIN (http://www.dynamsoft.com/Products/.Net-TWAIN-Scanner.aspx). It's a C# TWAIN & DirectShow Webcam Capture wrapper library. With it, you can implement document scan & image capture in WinForm/WPF applications easily. You can also try google '.net twain SDK' to see more options.

Disclaimer: I work for the company.