# Modify a film strip scan area

Tags: image-scanner

I need to modify a scanner that scans single film strip to A4 size.
I plan to modify the lid to luminate A4 size.
I have a Canon 5600F that has TWAIN driver.

The question I would like to ask, is the hardware driver resisting the sensor to scan the whole A4 area? or is it scanning A4 size and then cropping the image to film strip size?

Wondering if there any open source.

Thanks

Andy

Answer (score 0):

It depends the TWAIN driver, whether it supports automatic border detection. If not, you can also implement cropping after capture in your app.

What kind of application are you trying to develop, desktop or web? Do you intend to code based on the TWAIN interface or use a 3rd-party TWAIN SDK? If the prior, you can find some resources that might help in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16513786/using-twain-in-net-looking-for-resources/).